# Change table class in view block

Tags: views

Is it possible to change the table class when using drupal's format table for view. It seems to allow me to only change the row class.

Answer (score 1):

go to `core\themes\stable\templates\views` folder and copy views-view-table.html.twig or .tpl.php (depending if you are on Drupal 8 or 7)

copy the file and re-name it **views-view-table--[view-name]--[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg).html.twig** or **.tpl.php**

Then edit the file and add the class

**If Drupal 8**

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'cols-' ~ header|length,
    responsive ? 'responsive-enabled',
    sticky ? 'sticky-enabled',
    'my-custom-class',
  ]
%}
<table{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
```

**If Drupal 7**

```
<table <?php if ($classes) { print 'class="'. $classes . ' . ' ' . 'my-custom-class"'; } ?><?php print $attributes; ?>>
```

Now place your template file in your theme's template folder.

Clear/flush the cache to see changes.